# how can i create something like tabzilla?

Tags: jquery, css, mozilla

there is a navigation bar which can move down and show the menu in [Mozilla.org](http://mozilla.org)(i think it called tabzilla) at the top of the page,i want to know how can i create some thing like this? is there any library or ready source code in the jquery for it?

thanks

Comment: jQuery [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an experiment, I pulled Tabzilla out and set it to be stand-alone: https://github.com/msenateatplos/tabzilla

The jQuery lib is still remote.

You can either edit the CSS file or write to the LESS and use npm's less module to compile into css.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap 3.0, here is my suggestion: http://antonakoglou.com/making-tabzilla-with-bootstrap/

If you are in a hurry check it here: http://jsbin.com/EkAweqA/1

I guess someone can do something similar for the Foundation framework too.